# How can I export animation frames in WIREFRAME mode?

Tags: wireframe

I need your support :)

1. How can I export animation frames in WIREFRAME mode?
   I don't need renders, materials, cameras ... etc. just to export frames in wireframe mode as they look at my screen.
2. Also how can I change background color?
3. Is there option some of the objects to be in wireframe mode others in other visualization modes or modes affect whole scene?

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go into *View > Viewport Render Animation* and it will render in the folder you've chosen in the *Output* panel:

[image]

To change the background color open the *Viewport Shading*, click on *Background > Viewport* and click on the color block to pick the color you want:

[image]

In *Wireframe* display mode all your objects will appear as wireframes but if you want some objects to appear as wireframes and others to appear as solid you can switch to *Solid* display mode or any other one, select the object and in the *Object* panel > *Viewport Display > Display As*, choose *Wire*:

[image]